# Linq OrderBy logic

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to understand the custom sorting logic of the following LINQ query:

```
 var random = new Random();
 var cnt = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).OrderBy(i => random.NextDouble()).ToList();
```

What is the inner logic of such comparision and how does i compares to random.NextDouble() inside making the result list always different?

Comment: I 'm not sure what your question is. Each number is initially associated with a random double key, then the numbers are sorted based on their keys. Since the keys are chosen differently each time the sort order is different as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is equivalent to:

```
var cnt =
Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
.Select(i => new { i, rand = random.NextDouble() }) //"weave" the random temporary
.OrderBy(x => x.rand) //sort
.Select(x => x.i) //remove it
.ToList();
```

The random value logically becomes part of the list.

As an implementation detail (as of .NET 2.0 to 4.5), `OrderBy` materializes the sort key so that it is evaluated exactly one for each element. It does this for performance and (in your case) for correctness.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear that each time a new type { i, random.NextDouble() } is generating :)

Answer (score 4):

It is a simple implementation for shuffling an array. `random.NextDouble()` gives you a random number each time so the output sequence order is random.